# Connect points on scatter graph with gaps in series

Tags: excel

Have my data for my scatter graph setup as such

[image]

To generate this graph

[image]

Wish to have lines connecting the points in the seperate series however this only works when there is no gaps in the data between first and last point in series. How can I workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

There's an option when you select the data sources to ignore empty and hidden cells
[image]
Choose to "connect data points with line" here, and I think it will do what you want.
[image]